# What causes NotLeaderOrFollow Kafka exception through port-forwards in an otherwise working cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Given a Kafka 3.4+ Kraft cluster that is fully functioning inside a kubernetes cluster, what can cause a NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER from outside the cluster error given the following configuration:

- Three Kubernetes Nodes
- Kubernetes StatefulSet with Kafka running

  - `ADVERTISED_LISTENERS : BROKER://:9092,BROKER0://localhost:9094,BROKER1://localhost:9095,BROKER2://localhost:9096`
  - `LISTENERS : BROKER://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,BROKER0://localhost:9094,BROKER1://localhost:9095,BROKER2://localhost:9096`
  - `LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP : BROKER:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,BROKER0:PLAINTEXT,BROKER1:PLAINTEXT,BROKER2:PLAINTEXT`
  - PROCESS_ROLES : controller,broker
  - INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME : BROKER
  - CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES : CONTROLLER
  - Node IDs are 0,1,2 for nodes kafka-0, kafka-1 and kafka-2 respectively
  - `controller.quorum.voters=0@kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9093,1@kafka-1.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9093,2@kafka-2.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9093`
  - Shared storage for bootstrapping with cluster_id

This cluster is functioning correctly inside kubernetes. This was verified by performing tests using kafka-console-producer.sh from inside the kafka-0, kafka-1 and kafka2 pods.

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-0.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-1.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,kafka-2.kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic test
```

Through Kubernetes, the following port forward layout is configured to a local local machine

```
kafka-0 -> localhost:9094
kafka-1 -> localhost:9095
kafka-2 -> localhost:9096
```

Each node is configured with the same ADVERTISED_LISTENERS and LISTENERS as listed above.

The following is the result of testing against this port-forwarded cluster against a pre-created topic with 3 replicas and 3 partitions called `test2`

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9094,localhost:9095,localhost:9096 --topic test2
>test
>test
>test[2023-05-19 11:38:51,702] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 7 on topic-partition test2-1, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2023-05-19 11:38:51,703] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test2-1 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

Additionally, each node:port pair is accessible via `telnet localhost 9094|9095|9096` from the local machine.

What is invalid about this configuration that would cause a NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER when the reachable kraft node should return the leader's location.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not @hsp, I'm going to attack it again later once kraft is supported by more tools. I'll post an update here if I can figure it out.